# why my android project raise CPU usage range from 60% ~ 100%?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, service

Hello I'm making a chat application in android
so overall, I have a service which contains lots of classes and threads.
in my service, i had socket input read class, socket output writer class, and pinger that in summary have 6 threads.

Actually, i'm very new with this problem, well i can say i have no idea what makes a program occupy high percentage of CPU processes. is it cause too many static variables maybe? or too many running threads maybe, or too many local variables maybe?

I don't know exactly what is going on...?

So, please share with me your experiences and knowledge

**UPDATE**

```
public void run() {
        while(isRunning) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                if(!startCheck) {
                    //Log.v(TAG, "SocketQueue: "+socketTaskQueue.size()
                    if(socketTaskQueue.size() > 0) {
                        processSocketTask();// TODO
                    }

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

so basically, i made my threads like above example.
so, i have a vector called socketTaskQueue, and this thread job's is to check whether there's a socket task or not. if it does, then it will execute processSocketTask function that will get the top element of the vector queue and then remove it.

**UPDATE**

T.T this post is embarrassing! i forget to put Thread.sleep() in some of my threads!
SORRY FOR BOTHERING YOU GUYS! :p

Comment: **It could be anything really... who knows what's in your program, *certainly I don't!*** One thing is for sure tho, too many static or local variables are not going to cause your CPU usage to go up. The only thing that will cause your CPU usage to go up is code execution (from single or multiple threads).

Comment: Hi, i've inserted my code... basically i run all 6 threaads like this. is this kind of thread that makes CPU exhausted? please give me more clue...

Comment: per your last update: `Thread.Sleep()` is probably one of the least elegant ways to achieve what you want to. It's almost always a smell of bad code and you should avoid using it. For your example, you should use a scheduled task/timer of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused, usually, by threads that use CPU even when they cannot accomplish useful work.  For example, when a thread is waiting for something to happen, does it wait in a way that uses no CPU? Or does it keep waking up needlessly even before it can do work?

It can also be caused by threads that do work in extremely inefficient ways.

Comment: well actually, all of those 6 threads are keep running whether they got something to work or not. is that what you mean? threads in inefficient ways?

Comment: Yes, exactly. When a thread has no useful work to do, it should not be ready-to-run but instead be *blocked* waiting until it can do useful work.

Comment: Hi, please see my update. it shows how i usually run a thread... Well i just curious with blocking a thread. so please tell me how to do that :p

Comment: Rather than sleeping for some random amount of time, block on the queue.